# Javascript set timeout to bootstrap alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

My alerts are dynamically created.

Is it possible to assign a function to the alert to self destroy in 3 seconds?

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">  
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I am using `Django` as a backend.

The end product looks like this

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    My message
</div>
```

## Summary

Is it possible to make a timeout function like

```
setTimeout(function(this){ $(this).remove() }, 3000);
```

into the tags?

Comment: what you can do is once you appended the html to the `div` after that call a JavaScript function which will remove the content of that div after 3 seconds. you can use `setTimeout`

Comment: Yeah but is it possible instead assigning it to go like `<div class="alert alert-success" onCreate=setTimeout(function(this){ $(this).remove() }, 3000)>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy, albeit not the most elegant, way would to simply include a small image element with a script that ran once rendered. The fake source attribute causes the onerror JavaScript to execute immediately. The style causes the image element to not interrupt or alter the way the page renders.

This approach is easier because it doesn't require you to figure out which element needed to be targeted using some sort of data or iterator or custom identifier. It is slightly hard to read, but it does work. The timeout is set for 500 just so you don't have to wait 3 seconds to test it.

```html
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    My message
    <img src="close.soon" style="display:none;" onerror="(function(el){ setTimeout(function(){ el.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(el.parentNode); },500 ); })(this);" />
</div>
```

Alternatively, since you have included jQuery, you could also use this snippet as well:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    My message
    <img src="close.soon" style="display:none;" onerror="(function(el){ setTimeout(function(){ $(el).parent().remove(); },500 ); })(this);" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the keyword "modal" to the class list of alert div removes it from the DOM.

So below is one of the approach.
Give an ID selector then add the 'modal' to the class list

```
`<div id='myAlert' class="alert alert-success">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
My message
</div>`


setTimeout(()=>{
var alertId = document.getElementById('myAlert')
alertId.classList.add('modal')
},3000);
```